# Scan output of process and terminate if string found

Tags: bash, macos, shell

In bash, how do I start and "monitor" the output of a process for a given string?

Upon discovery of this string, I want to terminate the process.

E.g.

```
monitor myProgram ">>45Error;"
```

would launch `myProgram` and stop it as soon as it outputs `">>45Error;"`

Comment: You can't do that reliably since the output of that program may be buffered by the libc. That means that at the moment the string appears in output the cmd may have been finished already or at least it has done further work already

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean unless the program's code explicitly calls `flush()` the program will just `printf()` into a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `myprogram` handles/ignores the broken pipe signal (`SIGPIPE`), the following will do the job:

```
myprogram|grep --max-count 1 ">>45Error;"
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is the requested `monitor` script, built on top of [chepner's answer and comments therein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489506/6394138).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
fifo="$tmpdir/fifo"
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT

terminating_pattern=$1
shift

mkfifo "$fifo"

eval "$@" 2>&1|tee "$fifo" &

grep -q "$terminating_pattern" < "$fifo"
kill %%
```

Note that the input command line is executed using `eval`, which means that an additional level of expansions is performed. If that is undesirable, just remove the `eval`.

Testing:

```
$ ./monitor 49 'for i in {1..100}; do echo $((i*i)); sleep 1; done;'
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
./monitor: line 1:  9638 Terminated              eval "$@" 2>&1
      9639                       | tee "$fifo"
```

Comment: This is subject to the buffering issue mentioned by @hek2mgl. `grep` may not receive the string until some time after `myprogram` actually emits it.

Answer (score 0):

An improved version @Leon's answer that works even if `myprogram` ignores `SIGPIPE`:

```
mkfifo output
myprogram > output & pid=$!
grep --max-count 1 ">>45Error;" < output && kill $pid
```

However, output to anything other than an interactive device will be buffered, so there may be a delay (as @hek2mgl pointed out) between when `myprogram` writes the string and when `grep` can actually read the string. There are OS-specific ways to limit the size of the buffer associated with the pipe, or to disable it completely.

Comment: seems `--max-count` is not an option

Comment: Try using `-q` instead. You won't get *any* output, but it has the same effect as `--max-count 1` would if it were supported: `grep` will exit as soon as any successful match is made.

Comment: also doesn't work - do I need a different grep? `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: `grep -q` should work for any POSIX-compliant version of `grep`, but when you say "doesn't work", do you mean `myprogram` isn't being killed? This could be the buffering problem, which you can't do anything about in a portable way. You need to figure out how to avoid output buffering with `myprogram`. (One way would be with the `stdbuf` program, if available.)

Comment: I mean that instead of starting at all it just prints a `grep` usage

Comment: @chepner In your grep command you missed the string to grep for.

Comment: @minseong In this answer the grep command was missing the string to look for. See the updated answer, and if the `--max-count` version doesn't work, retry it with the `-q` option instead.

Comment: @Leon if I want to see output on screen can I make line 2: `myprogram | tee output $ pid=$!`?

Comment: @minseong First of all it must be `myprogram | tee output & pid=$!`. But this will bring back the problem of `myprogram` being immune to the `SIGPIPE` signal (since `$!` will now be `tee`'s PID). You can kill by the job id instead: `kill %%` (but you will may need to enable job control with `set -m`).

Comment: @Leon do you want to add a new answer with all of this info? I really don't understand perfectly what you mean just from the comment.  :(